# react native-mobx : there is way to use function in another page/class/component?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, mobx

there is way to use function **"navData.navigation.getParam("getData")(); "** in another page/class/component ?
i need to use some function in another page/class/component and i dont know to much how to do it with mobx

```
export default MainScreen;
MainScreen.navigationOptions = navData => {
  return {
    headerTitle: 'yellow',
    headerRight: (
      <>
        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>

          <Item
            title="sync"
            iconName={Platform.OS === "android" ? "md-sync" : "ios-sync"}
            onPress={() => {
              navData.navigation.getParam("getData")();
            }}
          />
        </HeaderButtons>
      </>
    )
  };
};
```